# Using "!=" operator for testing inequality instead of "<>" in Python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7

As I know using "<>" is deprecated for using inequality and "!=" operator should be used for this purpose.

Is it just a style difference or there is a difference in functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are [exactly the same](https://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/comparisons.html), though <> is deprecated like you said:

> <> and != are **alternate spellings for the same operator**. != is the preferred spelling; <> is obsolescent.